# How to convert array string to array in php

Tags: php, string, arrays

I have a string, which is comes from js using encodeURICompoent(). Now i would like to convert this string into array. I tried my level best to solve this. But i couldn't find any solution to do this. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
array string = 'array(0=>array("packid"=>22,"pverid"=>18,"yaml"=>"- url: /static
 static_dir: static

- url: .*
  script: provider.py" ),1=>array("packid"=>23,"pverid"=>19,"yaml"=>"- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: .*
  script: provider.py" ));';
```

Thanking you,
sureace

Comment: What do you want to extract out of those values? You need to use `implode` to convert string to array.

Comment: It's totally unclear what your string is. So far you have said that the string is JSON.stringified, in YAML format, URL encoded and in PHP array format. **What is it?!** The question is impossible to answer.

Comment: What i want is, I am getting json objects from client side to php, which contains encoded data string using javascript encodeURIComponent(). If it contains this data, i am unable to convert this object into array using json_decode() function.

jsonstring="{\"packid\":\"22\",\"pverid\":\"18\",\"yaml\":\"-%20url%3A%20%2Fstatic%0A%20%20static_dir%3A%20static%0A%0A-%20url%3A%20.*%0A%20%20script%3A%20provider.py\"},{\"packid\":\"23\",\"pverid\":\"19\",\"yaml\":\"-%20url%3A%20%2Fstatic%0A%20%20static_dir%3A%20static%0A%0A-%20url%3A%20.*%0A%20%20script%3A%20provider.py\"}"

Thanking you

Comment: *Why* are you mixing JSON with YAML with PHP arrays?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safely convert user-provided array string into PHP array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2143004/), [Convert PHP array string into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/684553/90527)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [`eval`](http://php.net/eval) should do the job of turning this string into an array.
***BUT:*** You should never, ever use `eval`, especially with input that you get from external sources, since it opens up a slew of security issues. Instead, you should parse the string by hand, but that's going to be quite a nuisance.

You should find a better way to send the array values, for example via [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json). Especially when sending values from Javascript, this is the usual method.

Comment: doesn't look that way to me.. looks like it would throw an exception at best. Looks like a good bit of the string is missing.

Comment: @no I think those newlines are part of the string.

Comment: When i am trying look like this, it throws parse errors.
$packs = eval($post["packs"]);
print_r($packs);
Errors
-----------
Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected $end in eval()'d code</b> on line <b>9

Comment: I am using JSON.stringify() jquery plug in method at client side to sending json data.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by deceze, you can use `eval()` to turn this string into a PHP array, but whether you should or not is another matter...

```
$myCodeString = 'array(0=>ar ...... etc.';  // Your coded string

eval('$myArray = '.$myCodeString);
var_dump($myArray);
```

Which at least returns a valid PHP array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["packid"]=>
    int(22)
    ["pverid"]=>
    int(18)
    ["yaml"]=>
    string(71) "- url: /static
 static_dir: static

- url: .*
  script: provider.py"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["packid"]=>
    int(23)
    ["pverid"]=>
    int(19)
    ["yaml"]=>
    string(72) "- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: .*
  script: provider.py"
  }
}
```

You probably want to parse your "yaml" fields some more...?

Comment: "you can use eval()" Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks for stressing the point, but I wasn't necessarily saying you should. There seemed to be some debate as to whether this was even technically possible.

Comment: This worked great for me. The security issue is only a factor if you don't have control over the data. In my case the array is auto generated and only exposed internal. No need to be paranoid.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.

Comment: How would `implode` convert a *string* into an *array*?

Comment: it wouldn't.. he meant `explode`, probably.

Comment: `explode` is for converting a delimited string into an array. The coded string in the OP is not a straight forward delimited string.

Answer (score 0):

it would be easier to use [serialize](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php) or [json](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) for transferring an array. (but in that case, you would need a little function on clientside for serializing / json_encode)

**EDIT:** if `encodeURIComponent` is you problem, just do a [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.urldecode.php) before json_decode...

Comment: Yes i am using JSON.stringify() function at client side

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand what you are asking here.

Do you want to convert a yaml string to an php array? If so, try [spyc](http://code.google.com/p/spyc).

Comment: yes, user always giving yaml data in textarea at client side. i am always getting that yaml data and  store that exact yaml data(with new lines, spaces...) in database for future purposes. Can u give some idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

yes i tried, but it dosen't solve my problem.

### What i want is, I am getting json objects from client side to php, which contains encoded data string using javascript encodeURIComponent(). If it contains this data, i am unable to convert this object into array using json_decode() function.

json string=packs="{\"packid\":\"22\",\"pverid\":\"18\",\"yaml\":\"-%20url%3A%20%2Fstatic%0A%20%20static_dir%3A%20static%0A%0A-%20url%3A%20.*%0A%20%20script%3A%20provider.py\"},{\"packid\":\"23\",\"pverid\":\"19\",\"yaml\":\"-%20url%3A%20%2Fstatic%0A%20%20static_dir%3A%20static%0A%0A-%20url%3A%20.*%0A%20%20script%3A%20provider.py\"}"

Thanking you,
sureace